# Counter in a loop is not echoed

Tags: batch-file

I have a for loop in a batch file. I get this weird behaviour with the counter variable. I am an experienced programmer, but a beginner in batch files.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET list=test1 test2 test3

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    SET variable=%%a
    ECHO %%a
    ECHO -%variable%-
)
```

I expect the output to be

```
test1
-test1-
test2
-test2-
test3
-test3-
```

but it actually is

```
test1
-test3-
test2
-test3-
test3
-test3-
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for not finding it - I had no idea that such a feature even existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual expected output is

```
test1
--
test2
--
test3
--
```

I would be astonished to get anything else; I definitely cannot reproduce your output.

Variables are expanded only once, when the `(` ... `)` construction is read. If you want that the assignments inside `(` ... `)` to take effect within `(` ... `)` you need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!variable!`. (Or, as some prefer, `call` a subroutine instead of using `(` ... `)`).

Comment: Indeed that's what I got the first few times - it's possible that I somehow polluted the variable in a global scope? Anyway, your solution works, so I'm going to accept this answer. Thank you!